# Does division operator ( / ) in C++ return the floor value in case of num with same sign and ceil value when both the numbers are of opposite sign?

Tags: c++, c++17

In C++ , when both numerator and denominator are integers and of same sign , then division operator gives the floor value of the quotient . But when they are of opposite sign , then it gives ceil value . Is my understanding correct or is there more to it ?

Comment: This is just truncation / round to zero

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Artyer I know it truncates towards 0 . But in terms of ceil and floor , is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Per standard: The binary `/` operator yields the quotient, and the binary `%` operator yields the remainder from the division
of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero the behavior is undefined. **For
integral operands the `/` operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded**; if the
quotient `a/b` is representable in the type of the result, `(a/b)*b + a%b` is equal to `a`.

Comment: The TLDR of that basically saying, "anything to the right of the decimal point is dropped"

Comment: @selbie I got your point . But my understanding in terms of ceil and floor is also correct . Right ?

Comment: @div3012 - I don't disagree with that interpretation. I think we're saying basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it right.  Some 20th-century hardware engineer decided to do it this way, and as far as I know this is how all microprocessors now natively do it.  Mathematically, it's often a little inconvenient, which is why Python (for example) corrects in software always to round toward toward floor.

For additional insight, besides `p/q` for an integer quotient, try `p%q` for the corresponding remainder.

Your question is tagged *C++* but this is really a computer hardware issue and, as such, it may be more helpful to consult the C17 standard, whose sect. 6.5.5(6) reads:

> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional
> part discarded. If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`....

(I have a shred of a memory from 25 or 30 years ago, reading about a CPU that rounded toward floor.  If my memory is not altogether imaginary, then that CPU apparently did not succeed in the marketplace, did it?)